# How to rotate elements either forward or back from current state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform

Say I have three elements. When user clicks on any of the elements, that element needs to rotate either +120 degrees or -120 degrees every time it's clicked (direction selected randomly with no particular order). So if it's current rotation is at 120, when it's click again, it rotates another 120 degrees. I need it to alternate between plus or minus rotation at random. So it can either rotate forward or back...

Here is the code I currently have:

```
var aElement = $(".element").each(function(){});

aElement.on('click', function() {

    $(this).css("transform", "rotate(120deg");

})
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the default state ? You can always multiply prev angle by -1, to make your angle positive or negative.

Comment: current state is just 120 deg.

Comment: Is expected result to toggle rotate from `0deg` to `120deg`, then from `120deg` to `0deg`? Or `120deg` to `-120deg`?

Comment: _"When user clicks on any of the elements, that element needs to rotate either +120 degrees or -120 degrees every time it's clicked. So if it's current rotation is at 120, when it's click again, it rotates another 120 degrees"_ Does element begin at `0deg` ? At first click set to `120deg`, at next click set to `-120deg`?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use **[`data-*`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** attributes to check if the clicked element is rotated of not using (1 and 0) then do the inversion, check the example below.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.element', function() {
  if ( $(this).data("rotated")==='1' ) {
    $(this).css("transform", "rotate(0deg").data("rotated","0");
  } else {
    $(this).css("transform", "rotate(120deg").data("rotated","1");
  }    
})
```

```css
.element{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img  data-rotated='0' class="element" src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/512/camera-icon.png' />
<img  data-rotated='0' class="element" src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/512/camera-icon.png' />
<img  data-rotated='0' class="element" src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/512/camera-icon.png' />
```

**Update**

For random rotation you could generate a random boolean and make a condition on it, check the example below.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.element', function() {
  var random_rotation_state = Math.random() >= 0.5;
  var rotation = parseInt($(this).data('rotation'));
  
  if ( random_rotation_state )
    rotation+= 120;
  else
    rotation-= 120;
  
  $(this).css("transform", "rotate("+rotation+"deg").data("rotation", rotation);
  console.log(rotation);
})
```

```css
.element{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img  data-rotation='0' class="element" src='http://haizdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/css3-featured.png' />
<img  data-rotation='0' class="element" src='http://az676930.vo.msecnd.net/media/1328/3_html5___css3_integration.png' />
```

Comment: Unclear what OP actually expects, though approach could be shortened further by removing `.data()`, checking current `transform` property for `-` or `120`

Comment: Thanks @guest271314 for your intervention, the OP want to switch between rotation degree 0 and 120.. actually the transform property return a `matrix` value (check the other answer) so avoiding the conversion to degree value i suggest to use data attributes.

Comment: _"the OP want to switch between rotation degree 0 and 120"_ Not entirely clear, here, what expected result is. See OP at  _"that element needs to rotate either +120 degrees or -120 degrees every time it's clicked"_ , _"I need it to alternate between plus or minus rotation. So it can either rotate forward or back..."_ `Element.style.transform` returns only `rotate(Ndeg)` here, if that is only `transform` property set; jQuery's `.css()` returns `matrix()`

Comment: Thanks for your code. This seems to accomplish what I need with the least code so I think this is most correct answer. Only one problem – I need it rotate left or right (negative or positive) on random. Currently it's rotating right and then left. But needs to rotate left right by random choice. I apologize if I didn't make that clear. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

I stand corrected. $(this).css('transform') doesn't give us the numeric angle. Instead it gives us something like this `matrix(-0.5, 0.866025, -0.866025, -0.5, 0, 0)`. Remember you need to do this for the rest of the browser prefixes.

Original Source: https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/

```js
$('.element').click(function(elm){
 var tr = $(this).css("transform");

  
  var values = tr.split('(')[1];
    values = values.split(')')[0];
    values = values.split(',');
var a = values[0];
var b = values[1];
var c = values[2];
var d = values[3];
  
  var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180/Math.PI));
angle = angle * - 1; 
console.log(angle);
$(this).css({ transform: 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});
  
});
```

```css
li{
  width: 50px; 
  height: 50px; 
  background: tomato; 
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="element"></li>
<li class="element"></li>
<li class="element"></li>
<li class="element"></li>
<li class="element"></li>
<li class="element"></li>
<li class="element"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var aElement = $(".element").each(function(){});

aElement.on('click', function() {

    if ($(this).css("transform") == "rotate(120deg)") {
        $(this).css("transform", "rotate(-120deg");
    } else {
        $(this).css("transform", "rotate(120deg");
    }    
})
```

Comment: it's not simple as you think ... https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/